# call a function inside a function in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

when calling `rest` function from button, then `start` function is called and prints values continues every second But when I call again `rest` function the `start` function call again but this time start function print values in 2x speed and so on.

But I don't want to print value in 2x speed. I am making a small project where I face this type of problem so that is why I write this small code. Please solve my problem

```
import tkinter as tk

window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry('400x400')

i = 0

def start():
    global i
    text_label .config(text=i)
    i += 1
    text_label .after(1000, start)

def rest():
    global i
    i=0
    start()

text_label = tk.Label(window, text="start")
text_label .pack()

tk.Button(window, text="rest", command=rest).pack()

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: I think an important question to ask yourself is: "What do I expect to happen when the button is pressed twice?" Should it even be possible to press the button twice or should you disable it after it has been pressed?

Comment: @fhdrsdg Why would the "reset" button be disabled? Then how would they reset it?

Comment: The button and function are not "reset" but "rest". I interpreted that as a button to press to keep track of how long someone or something is resting, but it could be intended as a reset button yes. In that case the answer to my question is clear, but in the way I read it it's not.

Answer (score 2):

What is happening is that every time you call `reset`, a new `callback` is launched that will call `start` indefinitely every 100ms. Every callback being independent, and having no knowledge of the others, this results in a series of callbacks each calling `start` on their own time, every 100 ms.

To avoid this "snowballing", you need to cancel the previous callbacks in order to reset properly. You do this by keeping a reference on the `callback`, and calling `tk.after_cancel(callback_id)` in `reset`.

Like this:

```
import tkinter as tk


def start():
    global i, callback_id
    text_label.config(text=i)
    i += 1
    callback_id = text_label.after(1000, start)


def reset():
    global i, callback_id
    i = 0
    if callback_id is not None:
        text_label.after_cancel(callback_id)
        callback_id = None
    start()


window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry('400x400')

text_label = tk.Label(window, text="start")
text_label.pack()

callback_id, i = None, 0
tk.Button(window, text="reset", command=reset).pack()

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Is `if callback_id is not None` same as `if callback_id != None` ?

Comment: hehe, yes, and no - in this case, yes. Look [here](https://realpython.com/python-is-identity-vs-equality/) for details.

Comment: `tk.after` returns a reference (a pointer) to the callback that you keep track of with `cb_id = tk.after...`. You then use this reference to cancel the callback with `tk.after_cancel(cb_id)`. The `tkinter/tcl` internals on how precisely this is implemented don't matter, but if you are interested, you can look up the code online.