# How to make a reset function?

Tags: python, tkinter

I've been making a timer program. as well as start, stop functions, I need to make a def reset(). but I have no clue what should I make a code. Could you give me a hint or an explanation?

```
import tkinter as tk 
import requests, json
from tkinter import font
from tkinter.ttk import *
from datetime import datetime

HEIGHT = 500
WIDTH = 600

second = 0
minute = 0
hour = 0
stp = 0


def start():
  global second, minute, hour
  sceond = sceond+1
  if(second = 60):
     minute = minute +1
     second = 0

  if(minute == 60):
     hour = hour + 1
     minute = 0

  if(stp ==0):
     lbl = Label(root, text = f'hour,minute,second', font('arial', 30, 'bold'),
     foreground = 'blue', background = 'black', width = 20)
     lbl.after(1000, start)
     lbl.place(x=60, y =80)

def stop():
    global stp
    stp =1              


   root = tk.Tk()

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, height=HEIGHT, width = WIDTH)
canvas.pack()

background_image = tk.PhotoImage(file='Clock.png')
background_label = tk.Label(root, image = background_image)
background_label.place(relwidth=1, relheight=1
```

Comment: You have a typo: `sceond`

Comment: Shouldn't the reset function just set all the time variables back to 0?

Comment: I just wrote an answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64463665/call-a-function-inside-a-function-in-tkinter/64464012#64464012), to do exactly that: It resets the variables, and cancels the ongoing callbacks.